# is there something like a "foreach" mode from the command line? Like in perl?

Tags: scripting, command-line

With perl we can run perl -p . That wraps a foreach loop around the code and executes the code on the file. What I'm looking for is something like

StringReplace[filename,"\t"->","]

and then I get a new file in which the string replace happened (the above would convert a .tsv to a .csv). Doesn't have to be StringReplace, can be anything that takes a line of stuff as input. Total[filename] would total all numbers in the rows of the file.

I do NOT want the whole file in kernel memory!

also like sed on Linux (stream editor -- works line by line)

That is like "scripting" the M command line-by-line (during MS-DOS we used to call that "batch mode" -- really means line-by-line).

Comment: So you want a global text search and replace within a file? I guess you could use e.g. `WriteString["newfile", StringReplace[ReadString["file"], "\t" -> ","]]`. However, I would guess that *any* dedicated command-line tool would be orders of magnitude faster than MMA at this.

Comment: yes. I guess I should have added: I do NOT want the whole file in kernel memory!

Comment: ... then same approach but with `ReadLine` + `StringReplace` + `WriteLine`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `-linewise` option to `wolframscript`.

Here's my little script, tsv2csv

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript -linewise

Print@StringReplace[$ScriptInputString,"\t"->","]
```

I tried it, via `./tsv2csv < in > out` on the file `in`

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h   i
```

and got

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

I believe the script is essentially called 3 times, because if I replace the `StringReplace[...]` with `"Foo"` the file `out` contains 3 lines, each says Foo.

Comment: I get: /usr/bin/env: ‘wolframscript -linewise’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines

Comment: What kind of system are you on?  I’m not sure I can reproduce, you may need to `man env` to see how to ensure the -linewise is seen as a parameter to wolframscript, rather than the whole thing being seen as one command.  The error message suggests `-S`, but my env works fine without any additional flags.  If I had to wager I’d guess -S goes before wolframscript in the shebang line.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a billion. I'm on Linux, Fedora 30. As per policy I'm supposed to wait a few days before I mark an answer as the solution, but I think this *is* the solution, so I'll upvote and select it. In the end, cut from the command line is still faster, the tsv -> csv was just an example, but it's good to know about the -linewise option.

Comment: Sure thing!  I recently have been battling wolframscript so all the options are in the front of my mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not robust but should be enough to get you started.

```
ClearAll[applyToFile]
applyToFile[filename_, typeSpec_, func_, batchSize_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{read = OpenRead[filename], write = OpenWrite[], readBach, 
   writeFileName},
  readBach = ReadList[read, typeSpec, batchSize];
  While[readBach =!= {},
   readBach = func /@ readBach;
   WriteLine[write, #] & /@ readBach;
   readBach = ReadList[read, typeSpec, batchSize]
   ];
  Close@read;
  Close@write
  ]
```

Then

```
SeedRandom[123]
fn = Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "nums.txt"}], RandomInteger[20, {5, 5}], "CSV"];
FilePrint[fn]
```

> ```
> 14,18,0,4,7
> 6,7,10,11,6
> 10,12,9,17,0
> 9,11,16,15,6
> 12,5,15,12,20
> ```

and

```
newFileName = applyToFile[fn, Record, StringReplace["," -> "\t"], 3];
FilePrint[newFileName]
```

> ```
> 14    18  0   4   7
> 6   7   10  11  6
> 10  12  9   17  0
> 9   11  16  15  6
> 12  5   15  12  20
> ```

Hope this helps.